# Push a var in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, push

Im fairly new to programming. Mostly I can find the solution to my problems online but not this time. I've found serveral posts about pushing a variable into an array, however when I console.log the array to check if the variable is actually in the array, he doesn't return the name of the variable that I want. What I get back is: [Card, Card], and what I want to see is: [card_Fireball, card_Waterbolt, etc]. The code I use is:

```
var Deck = [];

function Card(name, type, cost, points, damage, heal){
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.points = points;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.heal = heal;
    }

var card_Fireball = new Card("Fireball", "spell", 2, 1, 3, 0);
var card_Waterbolt = new Card("Waterbolt", "spell", 2, 1, 3, 0);

Deck.push(card_Fireball);
Deck.push(card_Waterbolt);

console.log(Deck);
```

The solution is probably fairly simple but I can't figure it out with my beginner experience :P Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You're not going to see the name of the variable. The console doesn't care what you named the variable, only what it's value is. Since you created a "Card" it's going to show "Card". If you click on what you *do* see in the console, you'll see that it has the correct objects.

Comment: if you open up each Card in the console you will see all the attributes of the card that you set

Comment: Try using console.dir instead of console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the card names with "Deck[x].name", where x is the index of the card in the array Deck.

To get all the names:

```
for(i=0;i<Deck.length;i++){
    console.log(Deck[i].name);
}
```

Assuming you name all your cards the same way as you did in your example, you could use this to get the variable names:

```
for(i=0;i<Deck.length;i++){
    console.log('card_' + Deck[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Also thanks everyone else for helping! Learned alot!

Answer (score 2):

You are doing everything correct just replace console.log with following:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(Deck));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an array of the variable names you have used, those are lost on the way.
In case you want an array of the names or any other property, try making a new array and pushing every value to it.

```
var names = [];
Deck.map(function(v) { names.push(v.name) })
console.log(names);
```

Output:

```
["Fireball", "Waterbolt"]
```